IMGUR API - 400 Status
I have followed the docs carefully and researched on google as i found that the endpoint had changed and the callback had changed. What else in here is wrong? I've tried for days, ive matched the callback "https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/browser-callback" when registering my imgur client_id. I only need the anonymous user connection too which i've read means you only need your client_id.

"For public read-only and anonymous resources, such as getting image info, looking up user comments, etc. all you need to do is send an authorization header with your client_id in your requests. This also works if you'd like to upload images anonymously (without the image being tied to an account), or if you'd like to create an anonymous album. This lets us know which application is accessing the API." - https://apidocs.imgur.com/

Screenshots attached of trying to use Postman as recommended for this GET request for access token with the relevant data.

This is my postman request
